# Is it safe to remove SharePoint\system SPUser from a custom sharepoint user group?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, administration, user

is it safe to remove SPUser "SharePoint\system" from a custom SharePoint user group?

```
<User ID="1073741823" Sid="S-1-0-0" Name="System Account" LoginName="SHAREPOINT\system" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" Flags="0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sharepoint\System* is actually the account used by application pool of your SharePoint web application in IIS. This account anyway has full permissions on your site and hence adding or removing this account from a group does not make any difference.